# Change content using javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm new to JavaScript, so I may not know all the details and features of JavaScript. Sorry for that.

Currently creating an Advent calendar.

```js
Calendar = function() {};

Calendar.prototype._showContent = function(day) {
  // The content box for the clicked day.
  var content = contents[this.currentDayIdx],
    title = content.querySelector('.content__title'),
    description = content.querySelector('.content__description'),
    meta = content.querySelector('.content__meta');

  console.log('current day: ' + this.currentDayIdx + ' day number:' + day.number);
  /* if user selects day 1, current day is 0 and day number is 1*/

  var d = new Date();
  var todaysDate = d.getDate();

  if (todaysDate == day.number) {
    console.log('today');
    content.classList.add('content__block--today');
  }
  if (todaysDate < day.number) {
    console.log('future');
    content.classList.add('content__block--future');
  }
  if (todaysDate >= day.number) {
    console.log('past');
    content.classList.add('content__block--past');
  }

  content.classList.add('content__block--current');

  day.titlefx.hide();
  day.titlefx.show(day.titlefxSettings);

  contentNumber.innerHTML = this.currentDayIdx + 1;
};
```

```css
.content__block {
  padding: 10vh 5vw;
}

.js .content__block {
  padding: 20vh 5vw;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 100;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-flex-direction: column;
  -ms-flex-direction: column;
  flex-direction: column;
  -webkit-justify-content: center;
  -ms-flex-pack: center;
  justify-content: center;
  width: 85%;
  height: 100%;
  padding: 3em 0 6em 7vw;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  -moz-user-select: none;
  -ms-user-select: none;
  user-select: none;
  -webkit-touch-callout: none;
  -khtml-user-select: none;
}

.content__title {
  font-family: 'Avenir Next', Avenir, 'Helvetica Neue', Helvetica, 'Segoe UI', Arial, sans-serif;
  font-size: 7vw;
  line-height: 0.85;
  margin: 0;
}

.content__description {
  font-size: 2.25vw;
  margin: 1em 0;
  padding: 0 0 0 5vw;
}

.content__meta {
  font-family: 'Avenir Next', Avenir, 'Helvetica Neue', Helvetica, 'Segoe UI', Arial, sans-serif;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0 0 0 2vw;
}

.content__meta::before {
  content: '\2014';
}

.content__number {
  position: absolute;
}

.btn-back {
  font-size: 2em;
  line-height: 2;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 100;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 2em;
  margin: 0;
  margin: 1em;
  padding: 0;
  pointer-events: auto;
  color: currentColor;
  border: 0;
  border: 2px solid;
  background: none;
}

.btn-back:focus {
  outline: none;
}

.no-js .content__number,
.no-js .btn-back {
  display: none;
}

.js .content__block,
.js .content__description,
.js .content__meta,
.js .content__number,
.js .btn-back {
  opacity: 0;
}

.js .content__block--current {
  pointer-events: auto;
  opacity: 1;
}

/* TODO: Change content */

.js .content__block--today {}
.js .content__block--past {}
.js .content__block--future {}
```

```html
<div class="content" id="my calendar">
  <div class="content__block">
    <h3 class="content__title">Day 1</h3>
    <p class="content__description">Description of Day 1 Event</p>
    <p class="content__meta"><a href="#">Click Here</a>
    </p>
  </div>
  <div class="content__block">
    <h3 class="content__title">Day 2</h3>
    <p class="content__description">Description of Day 2 Event</p>
    <p class="content__meta"><a href="#">Click Here</a>
    </p>
  </div>
  <div class="content__block">
    <h3 class="content__title">Day 3</h3>
    <p class="content__description">Description of Day 3 Event</p>
    <p class="content__meta"><a href="#">Click Here</a>
    </p>
  </div>
  <!-- (This goes on until day 31) -->
</div>
```

Structure to show each day preview (day + title + subtitle etc, when the user hovers one day).
structure to content of each day is title + description + meta(event link)

There is a calendar which shows all 31 days of December and once you click on them, a content page opens, which contains title + description and meta data. I have added these information in the HTML.
However I want, if user selects a future day, I want to change description and write something like "sorry! you cant look early".
Also I confirmed, with `content.classList.add('content__block--future');` it activates `content__block--future` CSS. It works flawlessly. For example if I change background to red in the CSS, it changes. But I cannot change the text of 'description'.

I tried to write `innerHTML` but failed. The website did not load at all.
The code is working fine right now, but missing future date feature.

Can you please assist me with this? Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Calendar.prototype._showContent = function(day) {
 
    // The content box for the clicked day.
        var content = contents[this.currentDayIdx],
        title = content.querySelector('.content__title'),
        description = content.querySelector('.content__description'),
        meta = content.querySelector('.content__meta');

     var d = new Date();
     var todaysDate = d.getDate();
  
      
       }
       if (todaysDate < day.number) {
           console.log('future');
           content.classList.add('content__block--future');
           
           description.innerHTML='Sorry.You can\'t look early! ';
           meta.innerHTML='';
         
        
       }}
```

Did the trick. I guess I was failed with syntax before. Thank you.